# How to fix the '!_debugLocked': is not true in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm new to flutter and I have a problem with the navigation. My app has multiple pages and I can't understand the error and how to fix it.

I searched online and I tried everything that I found on Git / Stack or Google but nothing works.

This is the error :  '!_debugLocked': is not true.

This is the code :

This is the first .dart file and the error is when I try to do the Navigator.of .....
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 320,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'C.R',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 120,
                  fontFamily: 'Membra',
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 200,
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            child: Image.asset('images/arrow_next.png'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  '/SecondScreen', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the second .dart file where I want to go to from the first file/ page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'NewWidget_Creator.dart';

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: NewWidget(
                'Schede',
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                    '/SecondScreen', (Route<dynamic> route) => false)),
          ),
          NewWidget(
              'Orario',
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  '/SecondScreen', (Route<dynamic> route) => false)),
          NewWidget(
              'Pausa',
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  '/SecondScreen', (Route<dynamic> route) => false)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

NewWidgetCreator .dart file :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  String Name_of_button;
  Future<dynamic> send_toNextPage;
  NewWidget(this.Name_of_button, this.send_toNextPage);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        send_toNextPage;
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          Name_of_button,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Membra',
            fontSize: 50,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what is inside `NewWidget_Creator.dart`? Don't you think, you overuse `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil`? Why do you remove all routes in navigator's stack? Isn't it easier to use `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/SecondScreen')`?

Comment: I posted the newWidget_Creator.dart file and I used Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/SecondScreen') butt I get the same error

Comment: Yeah, I know it doesn't affect on the problem, but maybe it'll make you aware what you want :)

Answer (score 2):

Why in `NewWidget` field `send_toNextPage` is a Future? Here you have fixed class of `NewWidget`

```dart
class NewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  String buttonName;
  String nextPageRoute;
  NewWidget(this.buttonName, this.nextPageRoute);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(nextPageRoute);
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          buttonName,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Membra',
            fontSize: 50,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how to use it in `SeconScreen`:

```dart
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          NewWidget('Schede', '/SecondScreen'),
          NewWidget('Orario', '/SecondScreen'),
          NewWidget('Pausa', '/SecondScreen'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

BTW: `SecondSreen` can be `StatelessWidget`:

```dart
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          NewWidget('Schede', '/SecondScreen'),
          NewWidget('Orario', '/SecondScreen'),
          NewWidget('Pausa', '/SecondScreen'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping me solve the problem.  I used send_toNextPage as a future because I checked what Navigator is and it sais Future<Object> but as I can see this game me an error, Next Time I will be more careful.